# Out of Sample Forecasting using Neural Network in Keras (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, forecasting

I am doing a time series forecasting exercise using the window method but i am struggling to understand how to do the forecast out of sample.
Here is the code:

```
def windowed_dataset(series, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(series)
  dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
  dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
  return dataset

dataset = windowed_dataset(x_train, window_size, batch_size, shuffle_buffer_size)
```

The function `windowed_dataset` split the univariate time series `series` into a matrix. Imagine,  we have a dataset as follows

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
for val in dataset:
   print(val.numpy())
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

the `windowed_dataset` function convert `series` into windows with `x features` on the left and `y labels` on the right.

```
[2 3 4 5] [6]
[4 5 6 7] [8]
[3 4 5 6] [7]
[1 2 3 4] [5]
[5 6 7 8] [9]
[0 1 2 3] [4]
```

In the next step, we implement the neural network model on the training `dataset` as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=[window_size], activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-6, momentum=0.9))
model.fit(dataset,epochs=100,verbose=0)
```

Up to here, i am fine with the code. However, I am struggling to understand the out of sample forecasting shown below:

```
forecast = []
for time in range(len(series) - window_size):  
  forecast.append(model.predict(series[time:time + window_size][np.newaxis]))
forecast = forecast[split_time-window_size:]
```

Can someone please explain to me why are we using a loop here for `time in range(len(series) - window_size)` ? why not simply do `model.predict(dataset_validation)` for the validation part and `model.predict(dataset)` for the training part ?

I don't understand the need for the `for loop` because this is not a rolling forecast we are not re-training the model. Can someone please explain to me?

While i understand why the data science community structure the `dataset` this way, i personally find it a lot clearer when we split the `X` and `y` and do the `model.fit` as follows `model.fit(X,y,epochs=100,verbose=0)` and the `predict` as as follows `model.predict(X)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop is returning the predictions in order, whereas if you call model.predict(dataset_validation) you'll get the predictions in a shuffled order (assumed you shuffled the dataset).

As for the point of using datasets - it can just help with code organization. There is no need to ever use one if you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. It makes sense to me now. I am reassured when I read that there is no harm in doing `model.predict(dataset_validation)` (assuming of course that the dataset is not shuffled). I am personally against the shuffling exercise (i know it kills the sequence bias) because it is important to keep the time series information untouched. In econometrics, for example, they don't teach that